# Llenar dataframe vacio en R

Tags: r, ciencia-de-datos

Hola estoy tratando de hacer mineria de texto en R y trato la manera de recorrer un dataframe como si fuera una lista similar a lo que sucede en pytho entonces he creado este codigo

```
palabras = c("dolor", "cansado", "#agotado")

todosTwits = c() #creo una lista vacia
  
for(i in seq((palabras))){
  twits = searchTwitter(palabras[c(i)], n=30)  
} #creo una lista con tweets 


append(todosTwits,twits) #intento agregar esos tweets a mi lista vacia
data_twits <- tbl_df(map_df(todosTwits, as.data.frame))#convierto mi nueva lista en dataframe
```

Pero el resultado cuando hago el append es una lista vacia alguien podria ayudarme en este error,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer problema es:

```
todosTwits = c() #creo una lista vacia
```

No estás creando una lista vacía, sino más bien un vector vacío, cosa que podemos verificar:

```
is.list(class(c()))
FALSE
```

Para crear una lista:

```
todosTwits = list()
```

El otro problema, es que en el ciclo, no estás "adicionando" los elementos, siempre te quedás con el último cuando haces `twits = searchTwitter(palabras[c(i)], n=30)`, por lo que si corriges lo antes mencionado con `todosTwits`, de todas formas el `append()` solo te dejaría la lista generada en la última iteración. Lo que buscas es mucho más sencillo, y de hecho, ni siquiera hace falta un `append()`:

```
todosTwits = list()
  
for(i in seq((palabras))){
  todosTwits[[i]] = searchTwitter(palabras[c(i)], n=30)  
}

todosTwits # Ya tenemos la lista
```

Comment: como recorro esa lista para hacerla un tbl

Comment: Una forma podría ser `do.call(rbind, todosTwits )`